# permission denied when call python script to run docker-compose ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I need to run python script just to run command : **docker-compose restart**,
but I got :

> dc restart: 1: /root/chat-9: Permission denied

and this my python code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

home_path = str(Path.home())
docker_path = Path(home_path+'/chat-9')
p = subprocess.Popen([docker_path,'dc restart'],shell=True)
p.wait()
```

note : **dc** is aliases from 'docker-compose'.

I had change chmod 777 -R for folder chat-9 also, but not working,

How to set permission so that python able to run docker-compose?

please help

Thanks

Comment: Can you post Dockerfile and docker-compose? or `CMD`

Comment: my docker file actually inside folder chat-9, to run nodejs, but if you want to see here : `FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true

RUN npm install
# RUN npm run build
# RUN cp -R src/views dist/views

EXPOSE 3000

ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.2.1/wai>
RUN chmod +x /wait

CMD /wait && npm run migrate && npm run seed && npm run start:nobuild
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it after I do sudo chmod 755 root and do sudo chown from root to www-data

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, use `sudo chmod +x <your_filename>` to make it executable.

Use : `sudo chown -R $USER <your_file>` to change the ownership from `root` to a user. `$USER` is the username.

Comment: I had change on popen(['path','sudo docker-compose restart']) and also on my python file script the result still same : sudo docker-compose restart: 1: /root/chat-9: Permission denied

Comment: Edited, please check

Comment: Still same T_T , my ubuntu is for server so it : root@server, I think my server doesn;t have any user besides root.

Comment: Try again by leaving `$USER` as itself. Only change `<your_file>`

Comment: the result is : missing operand after ‘restart.py’ ...